# MvxWindowsSetup or MvxStoreSetup cannot be resolved

Tags: android, mvvmcross, win-universal-app

I started with a Windows10 universal project, aswell as Xamarin. For this I added the current prerelease of MVVM Cross to my project. On the Android project it works without a problem. But on the Windows side it can't resolve any Setup symbol. But AFAIK this is needed to start the application.
References where set via NuGet for the Android project as well as for the Windows. But it looks like on the Windows Project the reference for the platform is missing.

The code is open source on GitHub: https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyManager/tree/mvx

Can anyone help me?

Thanks
NPadrutt

EDIT: the suggestion of Stephanvs to use beta1 was one part of the solution. The other was to install the mvvmcross.libraries instead of the mvvmcross NuGet package.

Comment: Which version of the nuget package are you using? I know the latest stable doesn't work, and there are some errors with the latest 4.0.0-beta2 package. For now, 4.0.0-beta1 should work with UAP packages, however there will be some breaking changes when moving forward after beta1.

Edit: After actually looking at your repo, I found out you're not actually using the MvvmCross package?

Comment: I use 4.0.0-beta2. I accidently linked the wrong branch, I'm sorry. I used MVVM Light so far. But since I want to port it to Android I want to move to MVVM Cross. Do you know what kind of breaking changes will come ?

Comment: Mainly namespace changes; see this commit: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/commit/8310e71a337f58fcac5e59ce55b557b2e69a7eaf

Comment: Ah alright, thanks for the info. It seems it works now. I guess I had the wrong NuGet Package. I added MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCross, instead of MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries.. Now it seems to work, even with the 4.0.0-beta2.

Comment: I have to correct myself. It seems 4.0.0-beta2 has issues with building.

Comment: Correct; there's an issue with a .rd.xml file missing; see the PR that fixes it here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/1109

Comment: ah, thanks for the information! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/1101 and https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/1109

The MvvmCross 4.0.0-beta3 will be released soon.